# syntax error, unexpected end of file when using include_once('header.php')

Tags: php, syntax, include-once

i just installed php 5.6.8 and my older scripts are considered as wrong, getting syntax error, unexpected end of file. On older PHP (5.2-5.3) it worked well, but now I don't know how to fix it to keep the functionality.

The basic problem is that in pages (like index.php) I use:

```
     include_once("header.php");
     include_once("some-page.php");
     include_once("footer.php");
```

In **header.php** I have things like logo etc that appears on evey page so it goes like:

```
<html> all-the-standard-things-here <body>      <div class="div_menu">
        <ul  id="menulist_root" class="mainlevel"><li id="menuitem_1">...</li></ul>    
    </div>
    <div class="div_body">
            <div class="div_center" >
              <div id="page">
```

then goes standard page, html code etc and i finish with **footer.php** closing the divs:

```
 </div> // end of page
 </div> // end of div_center
</div> // end of div_body
etc
```

But the server doesn't like the end of header.php showing:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\header.php on line 52 (which is the last line).

What to do?

Comment: Add the `PHP` code. There is something wrong. Not on the `HTML`.

Comment: pls show us the full `header.php`. You probably miss something in there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it was working without any change on 5.3 ...  it is a lot of code, but Ok, here it is. thanx for help.

```
<?php
include_once('default_functions.php');

if (!$security_check || $security_check <=  $_SESSION['user']['level']) {
    //ok
}   else {
    header("Location:users.php?action=loginAdmin");  
    die;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="sk" lang="sk">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
      <title>Slovenské firemné hry Zima | Elcop</title>
               <!--
              <link href="http://www.elcop.sk/templates/elcop/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
              -->
            <!--[if IE]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/elcop/css/ie.css" type="text/css" />
            <![endif]-->

            <!--[if IE 6]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/elcop/css/ie6.css" type="text/css" />     
            <![endif]-->    
    <link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  

 <?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
?>      
  <base href="" />
  <meta name="description" content="Individuálne kreatívne riešenia pre komunikačné potreby našich klientov predovšetkým prostredníctvom event marketingu a špeciálnych PR projektov."/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="elcop, korporatne bubnovanie, slovenske firemne hry, plazove inspiracie, teambuilding"/>
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="author" content="2create" />
  <meta name="title" content="Slovenské firemné hry Zima | Elcop" />
  <link href="http://www.elcop.sk/templates/elcop/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.elcop.sk/components/com_rsform/front.css" type="text/css" media="screen"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.elcop.sk/modules/mod_briaskISS/mod_briaskISS.css" type="text/css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.elcop.sk/media/system/js/caption.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.elcop.sk/modules/mod_xyo_swf/lib/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.elcop.sk/modules/mod_briaskISS/mod_briaskISS.js"></script>

    <meta name="author" content="2create" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.elcop.sk/templates/elcop/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.elcop.sk/templates/elcop/css/menus.css" type="text/css" />     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.elcop.sk/templates/elcop/css/content.css" type="text/css" />     


    <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/elcop/css/ie.css" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/elcop/css/ie6.css" type="text/css" />     
    <![endif]-->        

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.elcop.sk/templates/elcop/js/sfhover.js"></script>    

    <?php} else {?>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="content.css" type="text/css" />    
    <?php}?>

<?php  if(strlen($onload_css)) {        echo $onload_css;    }
   if(strlen($onload_script)) {        echo $onload_script;    }
   ?>

</head>
<body <?php if(strlen($onload_event)) {     echo $onload_event;   }?>> 

<?php

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost' && $_SESSION['user']['level'] >= 3) { 
    echo '<span style="color:red;margin:10px;">Work local (' . DB_NAME . ') !</span>';
} elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost' && $_SESSION['user']['level'] >= 3) { 
    echo '<span style="color:green;margin:10px;">Work online!</span>'; 
} else {

}?>  
    <div class="div_main_container">

    <?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost'){
?>  

        <div class="div_head">
            <div class="div_topbox">
                <div class="div_topmenu">
                    <ul class="menu"><li class="item14"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li><li class="item15"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/mapa-stranky"><span>Mapa stránky</span></a></li><li class="item16"><a href="javascript:window.print();"><span>Verzia pre tlač</span></a></li></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="div_languagemenu">

                </div>    
            </div>

            <br style="clear:both" />

            <div class="div_slideshow">
                <div class="div_float_logolink">
                    <a href="/./" title="Elcop s.r.o.">&nbsp;</a>
                </div>
                 <noscript>
     <div>ImageSlideShow requires Javascript</div>
 </noscript>



<ul id="briask-iss35" class="briask-iss" style="width:736px;height:152px"><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img1.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img4.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img11.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img9.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img7.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img8.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img6.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img2.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img10.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img3.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li><li><img src="http://www.elcop.sk/images/stories/Headers_2/img5.jpg" alt="Elcop" /></li></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var briaskPics35 = [0];
var briaskInstance35 =
    new briaskISS(35,1,2000,80, briaskPics35);
</script>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="div_menu">
            <ul  id="menulist_root" class="mainlevel"><li id="menuitem_1"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/o-nas" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_1">O nás</a></li><li id="menuitem_2"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/slovenske-firemne-hry" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_2">Slovenské firemné hry</a><ul  id="menulist_2"><li id="menuitem_2_1"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/slovenske-firemne-hry/sfh-zima" class="sublevel" id="menulink_2_1">SFH Zima</a></li><li id="menuitem_2_2"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/slovenske-firemne-hry/sfh-leto" class="sublevel" id="menulink_2_2">SFH Leto</a></li><li id="menuitem_2_3"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/slovenske-firemne-hry/sfh-plaze" class="sublevel" id="menulink_2_3">SFH Pláže</a></li><li id="menuitem_2_4"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/slovenske-firemne-hry/charitativna-iniciativa" class="sublevel" id="menulink_2_4">Charitatívna iniciatíva</a></li></ul></li><li id="menuitem_3"><a href="/bedminton" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_3">Bedminton</a><ul  id="menulist_3"><li id="menuitem_3_1"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/uastnicky-poplatok" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_1">Účastnícky poplatok</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_2"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/pravidla-a-herny-system" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_2">Pravidlá a herný systém</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_3"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/nominacia-a-nasadenie" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_3">Nominácia a nasadenie</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_4"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/bonusove-turnaje" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_4">Bonusové turnaje</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_5"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/hodnotenie" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_5">Hodnotenie</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_6"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/miesto-a-terminy" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_6">Miesto a termíny</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_7"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/najcastejsie-otazky-a-odpovede" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_7">Najčastejšie otázky a odpovede</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_8"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/prihlasene-spolocnosti" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_8">Prihlásené spoločnosti</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_9"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/fotogaleria" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_9">Fotogaléria</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_10"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/vysledky" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_10">Výsledky</a></li><li id="menuitem_3_11"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/bedminton/zaregistrujte-sa" class="sublevel" id="menulink_3_11">Zaregistrujte sa!</a></li></ul></li><li id="menuitem_4"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/golf" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_4">Golf</a></li><li id="menuitem_5"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/korporatne-bubnovanie" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_5">Korporátne bubnovanie</a></li><li id="menuitem_6"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/eventy" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_6">Eventy</a><ul  id="menulist_6"><li id="menuitem_6_1"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/eventy/event-marketing" class="sublevel" id="menulink_6_1">Event marketing</a></li><li id="menuitem_6_2"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/eventy/ponuka-eventov" class="sublevel" id="menulink_6_2">Ponuka eventov</a></li><li id="menuitem_6_3"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/eventy/public-relations" class="sublevel" id="menulink_6_3">Public Relations</a></li><li id="menuitem_6_4"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/eventy/event-manazment" class="sublevel" id="menulink_6_4">Event manažment</a></li></ul></li><li id="menuitem_7"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/referencie" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_7">Referencie</a></li><li id="menuitem_8"><a href="http://www.elcop.sk/kontakt" class="mainlevel" id="menulink_8">Kontakt</a></li></ul>    
        </div>
 <?php }?>       
        <div class="div_body">

                <div class="div_center" >
                  <div id="page">
```

Comment: well, I have it .... 5.6 doesn't like this -   <?php} else {?> - there need to be a space  before and after the bracelets.